# mousewheel.js is not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm designing a site which uses mousewheel.js. It renders awesomely when I load it in the desktop browsers. But when I load that page in mobile devices it is not working. Does anybody know why or an alternate solution for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mobile devices with mice?

Comment: @Joe touchscreen. I'm saying about the functionality(scrolling).

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor explanation.